# Access figcaption and img through figure id

Tags: javascript, html, css, figure

I really wanted to find this out alone... sorry for asking this question. I just started getting into HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

I want to access my figure's `img` and `figcaption` only through the figure's `id`.

```
<div id="grid">
    <figure id="hg">
        <img src="sml1.png"/>
        <figcaption>0</figcaption>
    </figure>   
</div>
```

I tried it with **`document.getElementById("hg").children`**, but that doesn't seem to work for me. Maybe I'm using it wrong?

Is what I want to do even possible? I don't really want to give the img and figcaption elements an `id` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the queryselector:

```
document.querySelector('#hg img');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `document.getElementById("hg").firstElementChild` or `document.getElementById("hg").children[0]`

`Node.children` returns a live HTMLCollection, not a single element. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children).

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [Node.childNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) to check if your element has childs.

> The `Node.childNodes` read-only property returns a live collection of child nodes of the given element where the first child node is assigned index 0.

```js
var myfigure = document.getElementById('hg');
// does you ID exists ? 
if (myfigure.hasChildNodes()) // has it got any child ? 
{
  var children = myfigure.childNodes;
  // if it does, get them
  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    // go through all children
    if (children[i].nodeName == 'IMG') {
      // is it an img tag 
      children[i].style.border = "solid"; // apply some style or whatever else 
    }
    // another test
    if (children[i].nodeName == 'FIGCAPTION') {
      children[i].style.color = "red";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <figure id="hg">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200&text=sml1.png" />
    <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

> The items in the collection of nodes are objects and not strings. To get data from node objects, use their properties (e.g. `elementNodeReference.childNodes[1].nodeName` to get the name